# php telnet fgets returns strange characters

Tags: php, character, fwrite, fgets, fsockopen

using fsockopen, fwrite & fegts to communicate with my account on a remote server over telnet using the following code:

```
$ip = "*hosts*";
$user = "*username*";
$pass = "*password*";

$fp = fsockopen($ip, 23, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) 
{
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
    exit;
    $utilitiesObj->hardFlush();
} 
else 
{

    echo "<br >We can connect";
    echo "<br >Sending user";

    $retFromFwrite = fwrite($fp,"$user\n");
    echo "<br >ret: ".$retFromFwrite;

        $line =  fgets($fp, 1024);
        echo "<br >line: ".$line;

    echo "<br >Complete";

}
fclose ($fp);
```

The output I get from the above is:

```
<br >We can connect<br >Sending user<br >ret: 8<br >line: ÿý%<br >Complete
```

Any ideas why I get the strange chars? When I login direct through a terminal this is that I get on the screen:

```
login: *username*
Password:
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you're doing raw telnet, you have to expect to get telnet control sequences.

Comment: Many thanks for your response Marc B. I tried adding a while loop to see if the response is buried in other lines but I still get the same output (ie the wierd chars).